# Как расположить элементы списка в выгруженном csv БЕЗ кавычек и скобок от [ ], каждую пару с новой строки?

Tags: python, парсер, excel, csv

Парсер, в одной из колонок дожны быть характеристики оборудования в виде:
В одной ячейке продукта:
***Макс. производительность : 205 м3/час

Макс. потребляемая мощность, Вт : 75 Вт

Напряжение электропитания : 220,0 В

и тд.***\

**Парсинг:**

```
prod_char = item.find_all('p', class_='char-tl')
prod_char_inf = item.find_all('p', class_='char-in')
prod_char_list = []
prod_char_inf_list =[]

for char in prod_char:
   prod_char_list.append(char.text)
for char_inf in prod_char_inf:
   prod_char_inf_list.append(char_inf.text)

product_info_combiner = list(zip(prod_char_list, prod_char_inf_list))
product_info_out = [x + ' : ' + y for x, y in product_info_combiner]

#..далее парсинг других частей..

# Составление конечного словаря из данных
product_cards.append({
                    'title':title,
                    'product_info':product_info_out,
                    'price':price,
                    'product_link':product_link,
                    'image_link':image_link,
                })
```

**Сохранение в csv**

```
def csv_saver(product_cards, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as result_csv:
        writer = csv.writer(result_csv, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow([
                        'Продукт',
                        'Характеристика',
                        'Стоимость',
                        'Ссылка на продукт',
                        'Ссылка на изображение',
                    ])

        for product in product_cards:
            writer.writerow([
                            product['title'],
                            product['product_info'],
                            product['price'],
                            product['product_link'],
                            product['image_link'],
                        ])
```

На выходе получается
***['Макс. производительность : 205 м3/час', 'Макс. потребляемая мощность, Вт : 75 Вт'....и тд. ]*** все в одну строку и с **[,,]**

Чувствую, что туплю и упускаю очевидное, леплю костыли...

Comment: все пишется в одну строку потому, что вы используете такой метод. что говорит документация по поводу `writerow` и  `writerows`?

Comment: вы вполне доходчиво объяснили. я же вам говорю, что вы используете метод `writer.writerow()`, который пишет одну строку, и намекаю, что нужно попробовать `writer.writerows()`, который пишет итерирумый параметр в несколько строк.

Answer (score 0):

возможно я не корректно объяснил какой должен быть вид у таблицы...
**сейчас вывод такой**
[image: сейчас вывод такой]

**а нужен такой**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

слышал что-то про вставку символа "переноса каретки", но не понял как реализуется.
Если передать в **writer** строку вида *"123\n456\n789"*, в таблице отображается как требуется, но передать нужные данные в таком виде не выходит

@strawdog , на счет метода **writerows**  - он раскидывают каждый элемент характеристик в отдельный столбец, что ломает всю таблицу